# Angular - Re-Populate form inputs from service

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a basic angular component that allows some one to edit the details of a user once they go to their profile and click on "edit".

**Component:**

```
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit {

    // Define our vars
    user: Users[];
    editUserForm: FormGroup;
    message: {};
    displayMessage = false;
    userID: number;
    errorMessage: any = '';

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private _userService: UserService,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // Get the userID from the activated route
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.userID = params['id'];
        });

        // Call our service and pass the UserID
        this._userService.getUser(this.userID)
            .then(res => {
                this.user = res;
                this.createForm();
            });

    }

    // Generate the form
    createForm() {
        this.editUserForm = this.fb.group({
            QID: ['', Validators.required],
            favoriteColor: [''],
            favoriteNumber: [''],
            favoriteActor: ['']
        });
    }

}
```

**Service:**

```
// Fetch a single user
    getUser(userID: number) {
        return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchUser', { "userID": userID }, { "headers": this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(err => { this.handleError(err); });
    }
```

**Interface:**

```
export interface Users {
    RecordID?: number;
    QID: string;
    favoriteColor?: string;
    favoriteNumber?: number;
    favoriteActor?: string;
}
```

I am trying to pass the values to my formGroup but I am having trouble figuring out how to access the values.

I assumed I could do something like this where I could access the user model and select a property from it but that is throwing an undefined error.

Would I pass the values here in the form group or bind them to the elements directly somehow? I am receiving the data back from the service just fine, just not sure how to get each of the values back to their respective fields.

```
createForm() {
    this.editUserForm = this.fb.group({
        QID: [this.user.QID, Validators.required],
        favoriteColor: [''],
        favoriteNumber: [''],
        favoriteActor: ['']
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly ... this is what my code looks like:

```
onProductRetrieved(product: IProduct): void {
    if (this.productForm) {
        this.productForm.reset();
    }
    this.product = product;

    // Update the data on the form
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        productName: this.product.productName,
        productCode: this.product.productCode,
        starRating: this.product.starRating,
        description: this.product.description
    });
    this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.product.tags || []));
}
```

I'm using `patchValue` for the values and `setControl` for the array.

OR

Since you are creating the form after retrieving the data, you could do something like this:

```
createForm() {
    this.editUserForm = this.fb.group({
        QID: [this.user.QID, Validators.required],
        favoriteColor: [this.user.favoriteColor],
        favoriteNumber: [this.user.favoriteNumber],
        favoriteActor: [this.user.favoriteActor]
    });
}
```

AND just to be complete ... each input element needs a `formControlName` property like this:

```
                    <input class="form-control" 
                            id="productNameId" 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Name (required)" 
                            formControlName="productName" />
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="displayMessage.productName">
                            {{displayMessage.productName}}
                    </span>
                </div>
```

You can find a complete working example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms

Comment: So your second example using the `this.user.QID` is my ideal solution and is what I tried first but I get the error of "Property 'QID' does not exist on type 'Users[]'.". I assumed it was right since its defined in my interface.

Comment: Is that exactly what it said? If so, then it thinks that `this.user` is an array. Are you getting an array back from `getUser` instead of getting a single user?

Comment: Oh ... I see ... you have it declared as an array up top: `user: Users[];` If it is not supposed to be an array, then change it to `user: Users` (without the array).

Comment: Ah good catch, this worked: `QID: [this.user[0].QID, Validators.required],`

Answer (score 0):

Bind a submit event to your form, then use this.editUserForm.value to access the data from the form.

In the component template:

```
<form [formGroup]="editUserForm" (submit)="saveIt()">
```

In the Component:

```
  saveIt() {
    if (this.editUserForm.dirty && this.editUserForm.valid) {
      alert(`Number: ${this.editUserForm.value.favoriteNumber} Actor: ${this.editUserForm.value.favoriteActor}`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looks like reactive forms ... so there is no need to pass it in from the template.

Comment: I am not trying to get the values entered into the form. This page has a few input fields that I need to fill in from the database (service call) so that they can be updated. Essentially I am setting the values of these fields to that of what is fetched from the database.